# Fungus in rear element (nikon 18-105mm) concern

Tags: fungus

Good day everyone, id like to know if someone had tried disassembling the rear element of your nikon lens(nikon 18-105). I am having hard time removing the fungus stuck between the glass since it seems that it has been glued very much. I've tried searching online guides but to no avail. Thanks you

[image: closeup view of fungus]

Comment: Are you sure that's fungus? It looks more like the glue holding two elements is allowing them to separate.

Comment: Apologies, please see this link instead for a clear view of the fungus itself https://ibb.co/zx99cXx. I'd still need to verify if this glue can be broken down since I haven't seen anyone online doing it. Replacement of this part is somewhat costly to my end which is why I am seeking advise from other users who've tried it before. I'm not also sure if this glass or the other end of the glass can be twisted same from the front element for removal since I find it difficult to do so upon testing.

Comment: Nope. Not going to click on a link like that. Sorry.

Comment: Kindly check as I have now updated the photo from my original post. thanks

Comment: This question has no question.

That photo looks more like crazing that fungus.

Comment: yes, i haven't used my lens for a while which is why it had that huge fungus. i'm planning on dipping it with a hydrogen peroxide for several days and see if it can have it removed.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked with other forum and it seems that this particular rear element lens group is not possible to be disassembled with. I'll be checking for possible online replacement part for this. Thanks